# Persistent Connection to server with PHP infinite loop

Tags: php, javascript, infinite-loop, persistent-connection

I want to keep my website updated one new information is added in the database. I can't use `Node.js` and `Comet Programming`, and `Javascript's setInterval` seems to be a bad idea because of too many requests.

Now I am using something like this  :

**Javascript :**

```
var url = "path_to/file.php";
var req = xmlhttp();
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.send(null);
poll = setInterval(getResponse, 100);
function getResponse()
{
  var data = req.responseText;
  var res = document.getElementById("response");
  res.innerHTML = data;
}
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
  set_time_limit(0);
  ob_start(); 

   while(true)
   {
    #CODE
    flush(); 
    ob_flush(); 
    sleep(0.3); 
   }

  flush(); 
  ob_flush(); 
?>
```

**Is this a good Idea? Can I use it with no problems? Maybe someone knows the better way to keep persistent connection?
(on my website will be about 500 online users)**

Comment: What are You attempting to do and what is the desired result? Why is there this infinite loop? This `flush(); ob_flush();` after Your `while(true){..}` will never be executed...

Comment: @shadyyx This example will be for a chat system, but I also have to display new information on the website once it is added to the database. (I my oppinion sending Ajax Requests Each Second will slow down a whole page). [ Thanks I will remove these lines. ]

Comment: I have never seen such implementation but AJAX requesting. If You consider each second is very time and server resources consuming You still can request the changes each 3 seconds or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push via [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) is an alternative, but only works for the latest version of browsers.

Your script has the disadvantage of asking every 100ms (this is very short), also when the latest ajax responses haven't arrived. I would change the script to ask the server for changes only if the previous ajax has arrived and a minimum time (timeout) since the last ajax has reached.

E.g. (untested):

```
function getResponse() {
    var data = req.responseText;
    var res = document.getElementById("response");
    res.innerHTML = data;
    setTimeout(getResponse, 500);
}
var url = "path_to/file.php";
var req = xmlhttp();
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.send(null);
getResponse();
```